# Yii Dynamic connection name

Tags: php, yii

I have 15 database connections defined in my config file  . Depending up on the user connection I connect to the corresponding database .

I can check user selection in SWITCH condition and can connect to the corresponding database .

But thinking is there any way I can do some thing like below

```
$connection = Yii::app()->{$this->my_dbselection};
```

Here I am trying to replace connection name with variable .But not finding the correct syntax for it .

Thanks

Comment: sorry I did some mess up . This worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever I mentioned in the question worked for me .

$connection = Yii::app()->{$this->my_dbselection};